# Filter data from python plot

Tags: python, plot, filter

I'm trying to filter some data from my plot. Specifically it is the 'hair' at the top of the cycle that I wish to remove.

The 'hair' is due to some numerical errors and I'm not aware of any method in python or how to write a code that would filter away points that don't occur frequently.

I wish to filter the data as I plot it.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Smooth function for this. to get rid of noice,

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Plot the Raw Data
# plt. Your Data >>>Bla Bla Blaa

smooth_data = pd.rolling_mean(ts,5).plot(style='k')
plt.show()
```

Comment: When I tried this I got 'module' object has no attribute 'rolling_mean'.

Comment: Im sorry. please change
pd.rolling_mean(ts,5)
to
smooth_data = ts_log.rolling(5).mean()

(pandas new version way is this)

Comment: Also there is another way to do this, using kalman filter (But it kinda complex- if your data is sensitive, like GPS data, transaction data-then you should try that. python got 'pykalman' lib for that....otherwise this mean fitting method is quite good )

and if you can please upload demo code with your question. so we can give better code-vice answer.